# I want to get the both ID and partyname , and want to return both.

Tags: android

I want to get both ID and partyname from the database and return both, and want to display the listitem,  but on clicked listitem ID should be passed to another activity not the partyname, Snapshot: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFiN9.jpg".

```
    public ArrayList<String> getPartyName(){

    ArrayList<String> partylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getDB();
    Cursor c;

    try {
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM RECORDS" , null);

        if(c == null) return null;

        String PARTY_NAME;
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {            

            PARTY_NAME = c.getString(3);
            partylist.add(PARTY_NAME);
            [![enter image description here][1]][1]

        } while (c.moveToNext()); 
        c.close();
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("login", e.getMessage());
    }


    return partylist;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your query like this:

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT id FROM RECORDS" , null);
```

replace id with the name of your id column.